# React Router with Multiple Switches Rendering Only First Switch Components

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I am working on a React App and is facing an issue as described below

This is my main Route Component having different layouts so I structured it like this.

```
export const AppRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <AuthRoute>
        <PublicRoutes />
      </AuthRoute>
      <PostRegistrationRoute>
        <PostRegistraionRoutes />
      </PostRegistrationRoute>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

My PublicRoutes file looks like below

```
const PublicRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={SignIn}></Route>
      <Route path="/signup" component={SignUp}></Route>
      <Route path="/confirm/:token?" component={ConfirmEmail}></Route>
      <Route
        path="/complete-your-profile"
        component={CompleteYourProfile}
      ></Route>
      <Route path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword}></Route>
      <Route path="/reset-password/:token?" component={ResetPassword}></Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

This is second Route file with Switch

```
const PostRegistraionRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/pricing-plans" component={PricingPlans}></Route>
      <Route
        path="/payment-success/:subscription_id/:invoice_id"
        component={PaymentSuccess}
      ></Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};

export default PostRegistraionRoutes;
```

AuthLayout File

```
interface ChildrenProp {
  children: ReactChild | ReactChildren;
}
const AuthRoute = ({ children }: ChildrenProp) => {
  const { state: AuthState } = useContext(AuthContext);

  return (
    <>
      {AuthState.isAuthenticated === false && <>{children}</>}
      {AuthState.isAuthenticated !== false && (
        <>
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
export default AuthRoute;
```

PostRegistrationLayout is also almost similar so not posting the code for that.

My problem is that I am able to just see routes from one file either AuthRoutes or PostRegistration routes. The one I keep at top of main routes file works. If in the main file I put PostRegistrationRoute above AuthRoutes then it starts rendering PostRegistrationRoute and shows blank page for AuthRoutes.

Using React Router v5

Kindly help in resolving the issue or suggest an idea for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Well this was a silly mistake but if anyone else bumps into similar situation your main routes should be under single route like below

```
export const AppRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route>
        <AuthRoute>
          <PublicRoutes />
        </AuthRoute>
        <PostRegistrationRoute>
          <PostRegistraionRoutes />
        </PostRegistrationRoute>
        <PrivateRoute>
          <DashboardRoutes />
        </PrivateRoute>
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  );
};
```